# C#: GroupEvent inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

here is my GroupNews model :

```
class GroupEvent
{
[Key]
public int GroupEvenID { get; set; }

public int GroupID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("GroupID")]
public virtual Group RelatedGroups { get; set; }

public int EvenID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("EventID")]
public virtual Event RelatedEvent { get; set; }
```

}

and the repository :

```
public class GroupEventRepositoryDB : RepositoryBase<GroupEvent>, IGroupEventRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GroupEventRepositoryDB"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="databaseFactory">The database factory.</param>
    public GroupEventRepositoryDB(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        : base(databaseFactory)
    {
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// GroupEvent repository interface.
/// </summary>
public interface IGroupEventRepository : IRepository<GroupEvent>
{
}
```

but GroupEvent is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: make your `class GroupEvent` as `Public` like `Public class GroupEvent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
class GroupEvent
```

to

```
public class GroupEvent
```

Answer (score 1):

use `public` access specifier, by default it's `Internal` use

```
public class GroupEvent
```

Visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/7f45fat0.aspx)

Comment: by default its `internal` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: By default it's internal not private